# Display blog posts from Wordpress to my Drupal site and filter it by taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am new to Drupal and need some help. I have a Wordpress blog and a Drupal (version 7) website. I want to display a few blog posts from Wordpress onto my Drupal site. The problem is that I want to select/filter the blog posts based on taxonomy terms I've created in Drupal (blog posts will have corresponding tags for filtering). How can I do this?

Comment: What's the database format of that Wordpress site that contains those blog posts? And how are the taxonomy terms technically implemented in that Wordpress site (is it some specific table, or something else)?

Comment: Database is MySQL. Fields include title, author, categories, tags, date... What are you suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated. You'll need to fetch the data somehow from WordPress and make it Drupal data. Fortunately, there's the [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) that can help you getting data from your WordPress and transforming it into Drupal nodes. You'll need to configure the Feeds to also parse WordPress categories and create taxonomy terms from it.

I recommend you to read the Feeds documentation before start using it.

Comment: I attempted the feeds module but for some reason the categories and tags fields doesn't get pulled into drupal nodes. Is there a specific setting that needs to be applied?